# Assign names stored in a file to numbers stored in a second file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have two files:

```
>head(fileA)
   2    1   544.8  1279.2   1.0603  3.2460  0.0542 
   3    1   546.2  1277.8   1.0463  3.2460  0.0553 
   3    2   543.9  1280.1   0.1652  3.2460  0.0177 
   4    1   543.7  1280.3   1.0819  3.2460  0.0527 
>head(fileB)
1 Coly
2 Mony
3 Fong
4 Wow
5 Poly
```

I would like to assign the names in fileB to the number in fileA, to get the following output

```
   2 Mony   1 Coly   544.8  1279.2   1.0603  3.2460  0.0542 
   3 Fong   1 Coly  546.2  1277.8   1.0463  3.2460  0.0553 
   3 Fong   2 Mony  543.9  1280.1   0.1652  3.2460  0.0177 
   4 Wow    1 Coly   543.7  1280.3   1.0819  3.2460  0.0527
```

To be honest I was not able to try anything, I just spent a lot of time looking up how to do this. The only thing that I thought about was to assign the numbers in fileA to variables and then every time this variables are found append to it the content of fileB. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this.

Any suggestion, link, directive?
Thanks

Comment: The only reasonable solution I see is to use a full scripting language, like Python or Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash's read, and grep and tr:

```
cat fileA | while read i j k ; do
  grep "^$i\W" fileB | tr '\n' ' '
  grep "^$j\W" fileB | tr '\n' ' ' 
  echo $k 
done
```

Comment: wow that is great! Would you mind to explain it a bit?

Comment: I tried now on another file, but it seems to mess up all the results when there are number >9, meaning with two character. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Ah, right, forgot about that. Need to use this instead:
`grep "^$i\W" fileB` and etc

Comment: To explain a bit:  `cat fileA | while read i j k` will take in lines from fileA one at a time, and split them on spaces into the i (first column, space delimited), j (second column) and k (remainder).  Then grep for $i searches for that pattern (in my edit, it now searches for the whole word $i at the beginning of the line, not just a partial match) in fileB, and the tr will replace the trailing newline with a space. Repeat this for $j, and then the echo $k prints the rest of the line (now including the trailing newline).

Comment: thanks very much, but it still mess up quite a bit, I have  multiple entry fileB in the line of interest in filA.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have duplicate lines in your fileB?  If so, then you can process them to be unique with `uniq fileB` (can also use `sort` if they are out of order, ie `sort -n fileB | uniq`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35753/discussion-between-user100375-and-efrem).

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $B, '<', 'B' or die $!;
my %name_of;
while (<$B>) {
    my ($num, $name) = split;
    $name_of{$num} = $name;
}

open my $A, '<', 'A' or die $!;
while (<$A>) {
    my @F = split;
    splice @F, 2, 0, $name_of{ $F[1] };
    splice @F, 1, 0, $name_of{ $F[0] };
    print "@F\n";
}
```

The second paragraph reads the B file into a hash table, mapping numbers to names. The third paragraph reads the A file, splits each line into an array, inserts the names retrieved from the hash table according to the first two columns into the array, and prints it.